# Keeping record of disk usage in Debian

Tags: debian, disk-usage, gnuplot

I stumbled across this beautiful program `ncdu` and it definitely is a great program to view your diskspace. But however if i want to keep a track of my disk usage, it provides not options to export the data in record format, i.e. graph or plot or any specific format.

[image]

One thing i can do is take the text output of this command and keep it in text file which is not only extra labour also ineffective and wrong.

Are there any methods to achieve what i am try to do. Note that my ultimate goal is to keep track of Disk Usage so that i can browse the folder structure of `/` and respective disk usage of, say, 2 weeks ago and i can switch to another program if applicable.

**EDIT**

As some people suggested about the inbuilt parameters of `ncdu`, I am well aware of those and not looking for that, instead i am looking for something like a IMAGE or PLOT representing the data and usage. Somehow like, `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg`

[image]

Comment: Did you read `man ncdu`? Check the flags `-o` and `-f`, it does exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know about this, i was hoping for something like `export the data in record format, i.e. graph or plot or any specific format.` As in graph or image. not the raw data format.

Answer (score 2):

Create a report to inspect later, containing information about the current directory (and subdirectories), saved in `reportfile`:

```
ncdu -o reportfile
```

Opening the previously created report:

```
ncdu -f reportfile
```

From `man ncdu`:

> -f FILE
>
> Load the given file, which has earlier been created with the "-o" option. If FILE is equivalent to "-", the file is read from standard input.
>
> [...]
>
> -o FILE
>
> Export all necessary information to FILE instead of opening the browser interface. If FILE is "-", the data is written to standard output.  See the examples section below for some handy use cases.
>
> Be warned that the exported data may grow quite large when exporting a directory with many files. 10.000 files will get you an export in the order of 600 to 700 KiB uncompressed, or a little over 100 KiB when compressed
>              with gzip. This scales linearly, so be prepared to handle a few tens of megabytes when dealing with millions of files.
>
> For the sake of preventing a screw-up, the current version of ncdu will assume that the directory information in the imported file does not represent the filesystem on which the file is being imported. That is, the
>              refresh and file deletion options in the browser will be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but i was aware of this function and thinking more like `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg` this way gives a more readable format, i.e. a plot or graph.